# Confidential content - how to make a webM video file which is not downloadable by anyone but only viewable via Google Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, php, apache, google-chrome, webm

I have a confidential video file, which i need to show this afternoon only to a person, 
but at the same time i have to make sure nobody else can download this content but only view it via Google Chrome web browser. (if you are smart you can record it via screen capture or video camera, but not really easy downloadable file)

Is it possible some how? How do i do that? visitor will go to a public url: `www.mywebsite.com/join/contents/meeting`

```
<?php
$title = ($_GET['title']=='' ? 'ab' : $_GET['title']);
$button = ($_GET['butotn']=='' ? 'video' : $_GET['button']);
$refresh = ($_GET['refresh']=='' ? '5' : $_GET['refresh']);
$id =  ($_GET['id']=='' ? 'ab' : $_GET['id']);

$play =  ($_GET['play']=='' ? 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm' : $_GET['play']);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><?php echo $title;?></title>
  <script src="/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css"> 
  <script>

    function video_play1() {
      $( "#presentationVideo" ).hide();
      $('#mediaplayer').attr('src', '<?php echo $play;?>').show();
      document.getElementById('mediaplayer').play();
    }

    window.onload = function() {
      video_play1();
    }



  </script>    
</head>
<body>
<video id="mediaplayer" autoplay="autoplay"  poster="/images/vlc.jpg"  type="video/webm" loop ></video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Generally, if you can play something in a browser, you can download it. That's why Silverlight exists. Hard to give an answer without a definition of "easily downloadable".

Comment: Playing RTSP streams i mean which is not easy to download but watch it only.